# Is there a way for me to disable a command for a certain role in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Exactly what the title says. I have someone abusing a certain command that I would like to restrict a role that they have from using said command. Is there a ay to do that? and if so, can someone please write the example code?

Comment: Please refer to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=check#checks)

Comment: Could you share the code you have so far?

Comment: @PirateNinjas

@client.command(pass_context = False)
@commands.has_role("Mem")
async def clear(ctx, amount=0):
 if (ctx.message.author.permissions_in(ctx.message.channel).manage_messages):
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit= amount+1)
  role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Mem', ctx.message.guild.roles)

i get no errors when running the bot, although the clear command doesnt work for anyone anymore now, which is why i want to know if someone could rewrite this so that way it works

Answer (score 0):

under the decorator for your command (`@bot.command()`) use `@commands.has_role("roleName")` to limit the command to only that role.